# window.open remove reference from parent

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have one page with list of reports and after clicking on report it redirects me to internal report page in new tab with:

```
window.open(reportIdUrl,reportId);
```

So when i am back on report list and i want to open same report i will use

```
window.open("",reportId);
if(redirect.location.href === "about:blank" || redirect.location.href !== '<internalreportpage>') {
        redirect = window.open(reportUrl,reportId);
        redirect.focus();
    } else {
        redirect.focus();
    }
```

But when someone from new tab with internal report page navigates somehow to report list page (within this tab) and then tries to open internal report page it will open it in same tab as it is tab reference not content reference.

Does anybody know some way to drop reference when i access if condition?
Something like:

```
window.open("",reportId);

    if(redirect.location.href === "about:blank" || redirect.location.href !== '<internalreportpage>') {
            window.dropReference(reportId) //change_me
            redirect = window.open(reportUrl,reportId);
            redirect.focus();
        } else {
            redirect.focus();
        }
```

So it will create new tab with new reportId reference?

Thanks

## EXAMPLE

--reportlistpage

```
linkToReport1 (window.open(report1Url,1))
linkToReport2 (window.open(report2Url,2))
.
.
.
```

- You click on linkToReport1 - 2 tabs are opened. One with reportlistpage and one with internal-report/report1.
- You go back to parent tab and click to linkToReport1. Tab is opened with reference to "1" and will focus to it and no new tab is opened (this is ok).
- You are on linkToReport1 and you redirect with some menu hyperlink to reportlistpage (within linkToReport1 tab). Url changed to /report-list
- You click to linkToReport1. Nothing happen (this is not ok) because you are on the tab with reference to 1 (content and url changed), now you want to open a new tab with /internal-report/report1 url and store it as 1 with window references.

Comment: Make your window's name unique? Or do you need sometimes to use the same window?

Comment: sure, same report needs same tab. So if it is opened and contains internalreportId content it should just focus to that and not opening new one. Once someone redirects somewhere (e.g. report list) and then wants to redirect, reference should be dropped

Comment: I'm a bit lost in your process... What makes the toggling of a new page? Only the fact they did visit one other page? What if they come back to the original tab? Is there no way for you to simply give an unique id to your parent page and append it to the target name? If ypu don't care abput previous connections, then you could store a token (e.g in localStorage) and update it when needed.

Comment: i will add example to question

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is bit simple when you realize you can set or reset window.name. So there is nothing like references from parent.

Based on content you can do something following. In the page you want to keep track in tab,
at the beginning (in my case internalReport id):

```
var currentWindow = window.self;
currentWindow.name = reportId; //this is in case someone manually opened it without window.open(internalReportUrl, reportId)
```

then bind resetting of ***window.name*** on *beforeunload* event (e.g.):

```
var resetWindowName = function() {
    var currentWindow = window.self;
    currentWindow.name = ""
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', resetWindowName);
```

So when you redirect from internalreportpage somewhere, name is cleared and you can repeadetly call

```
window.open(internalReportUrl,reportId)
```

which will open new tab for you.